# Applying for a UK visa for 4 family members. Received only 3 notifications from UK visa section Croydon

Tags: group-travel

Our family (2 adults and 2 children) applied for UK tourist visas. We applied together. Last Friday 3 of us received 3 emails from the UK Visa Section Croydon:

“Your UK visa application has been despatched from the UK Visa Section. 
If you submitted your application at a visa application centre you will receive an email within 1-2 working days from TLS or VFS on collecting your decision. Please ensure you check your e-mail account.”

However, my smallest daughter has not received the same message. Is there any contact number that I can call and ask if our daughter’s application has been assessed?

I tried to call the following numbers: 00448435047198/00443001232241 but there were no option for me to ask our situation. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Perhaps the ECO handling your applications went home for the weekend,  having processed three of the four. He'll resume on Monday, and your notification will arrive today. Or maybe one of your four applications has been selected at random for a second assessment and your notification will arrive tomorrow. It's still only 1130am on Monday in Croydon. I'd suggest waiting 48hours before following up on things.

Comment: @CannonFodder: Thank you very much for your reply. Do you know which phone number i can call to follow up on things, e.g to ask about my daughter application process status. People in the tls uk visa application centre in Berlin told us that, the process will take 2-3 weeks. Today is 3 weeks. We (3 of us) have recently received emails that our passports have been sent to us. We are really waiting for the 4th passport :(.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, we got the last visa after 6 weeks (3 weeks after receiving the other 3 visas).
Here I would like to inform about what to do if someone faces the same situation. 
Sometimes they take the applications randomly to assess the visa. I had to call the service (00 44 203 481 1736) 3 times to explain my situation. The first woman said that the application status is pending and I should call again after 3 days if I don't receive an update. When I called for the second time, the agent said: "the application is pending but I will expedite the process". When I checked for the third time (a day after) the agent informed that my application was now in process. I received the visa  1 week after the third call.
So my suggestion is to be patient in this situation but we also need to call the helpline and check the status if we do not receive any notification within 3 weeks. As the woman in the customer support said that she can help so that the status changes from "pending" to "in process". But once the status is "in process", they can not do anything else. 
Good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

Contacting [UK Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english) is a fee-based service:

> You can call or email English-speaking* staff with a question about your application.
>
> By phone
>   Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> By email
>   [Email UK Visas and Immigration](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English). 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.
>
> You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and UK [public holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays).

*Service is [available in other languages.](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk?previous_response=english)